# Discord.js : Creating channels within Categories

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a bot which designs a server so its job is to make channels and roles so the owner doesnt have to waste time setting up the server. This is my code:

```
  if (message.content === 'tchannel') {
      message.guild.channels.create('Important', {
        type: 'category',
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
              id: message.guild.id,
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          }]
      })
      
      message.guild.channels.create('Rules', {
          type: 'text',
          permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                  id: message.guild.id,
                  allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
              }]
          })
       
  message.channel.send("Channel Created!")
    }
```

**What im wondering is, if there is a way to make the text channel connect to the category and not made seperately?**

(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/730705963018879007/730771756784156752/lol.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need for the parameter `cat` to have `cat.parentID`. Just put `cat` and it should be fine.

Example Code:

```
message.guild.channels.create('Important ', {
                type: 'category',
                position: 1,
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: message.guild.id,
                        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    }]
            }).then(cat => {
                message.guild.channels.create('Rules', {
                    type: 'text',
                    parent: cat,
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: message.guild.id,
                            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                        }]
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the .then method and get the parentID from it. Either you can assign the category to a variable and assign it after if you will use it anyone else.

```js
    message.guild.channels.create('Important', {
        type: 'category',
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
              id: message.guild.id,
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          }]
      }).then(cat => {
        message.guild.channels.create('Rules', {
            type: 'text',
            parent: cat.parentID,
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                }]
            })
      })
```

Comment: Thank you but that sadly didnt work ;( (im using v12 btw)

Comment: it doesnt log an error it just makes the category and the text channel seperately

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you mean is that when you execute the command to create the channel, it has to create it under the category of the current channel.

If so, you need this:

```js
const category = client.channels.cache.get(message.channel.parentID)
```